# How to get the actual type of object

Tags: c#

I want to get the actual type of an object even though I convert it to other types like for example I have an `Integer` and convert it to `Object`, is there a way to find out how?

Comment: You can use `GetType().Name` to get the name of the type, but using `GetType()` is preferred since text comparisons can cause issues with types. If you want the original value in unboxed form than you can cast as the known type such as `(int)x`

Comment: If you **convert** an object to another type then you are creating a brand new object. If you **cast** an object to another type then you are referring to the same object as if it were the new type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET has `.GetType()` as part of every object. You could use this to do stuff with reflection.

C# also has pattern matching:

```
if (obj is int intVal)
{
    // use as an integer
}
```

When you cast or box any value from one type to `System.Object`, it still under the covers has the same value.

Comment: @PerpetualJ my first sentence should cover that too

Comment: "has the same value" -> "has the same **type**"

Comment: @Enigmativity If it has the same value then it has the same type too, otherwise it would not be the same value

Comment: @SirRufo - Yes, I see what you're saying. It just doesn't seem like it's what was intended here.